# How can I see my latency/ping in Diablo III?

Tags: diablo-iii

Is there any way to display the current latency or ping in the game?

I'm seeing some strange behaviour with my skills, sometimes they're not working at all and I'd like to verify that these problems are caused by lag as I suspect. It would also be useful to determine the amount of latency *before* dying to some elite mobs due to that latency.

Comment: roll a four sided dice, multiply the result by 100.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There's a green/yellow/red vertical bar next to your *mana/spirit* globe. If you hover over it it will tell you exact latency value in milliseconds.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I completely overlooked that bar the whole time I've been playing now.

Comment: Took me some accidental luck to find it's even there and not a graphical eye-candy )

Comment: on mine, green seems to mean 200-400

Comment: @horatio indeed, Blizzard's definition of 'good latency' appears to disagree with every gamer in the world. Green bar + rubber banding is awesome.