# I'm the only one moving around?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have something weird going on in Diablo 3 - first I only had a 1GB DDR2 graphics card which allowed me to play solo without a problem but during public games the framerate dropped to below 10.

I changed the card for a 2GB GDDR5 graphics card (and some other stuff) and now during public play I get moments during the game that I'm the only character moving around.

After a short period of time all characters start to move again and all my attacks I used during these seconds go off.

My framerate isn't a problem anymore - even on high settings.

Does anybody know where this comes from?

Comment: Sounds like network lag, and therefore probably unrelated to your video card upgrade. Perhaps you just notice it more now that you play multiplayer games?

Comment: Yes, that is lag, see if you can enable a ping monitor on the game, if that goes up high when you are the only one moving, then it is lag

Answer (score 8):

This issue is caused by network latency rather than any graphical issue. While Diablo 3 is unable to contact the game server, everybody else will seem to stand still (as your game is receiving no information saying that they're moving).

This could be caused by your internet service provider in that your internet connection temporarily stops sending or receiving data, it could also be caused by your local network - for example if you're using wireless you could be using a wireless channel that has a lot of contention or a dodgy network cable if you're wired.

It could also be caused by Diablo 3's game servers, although if this was the case it would be affecting a lot more people than just yourself.

In order to diagnose this issue I would try some of the following;

- [How can I see my latency/ping in Diablo III?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/67557/27134) - hovering over this will show you your latency in MS - high numbers (300+) are bad, low numbers are good.
- Does this problem occur in any other multiplayer games? If it does, this rules out the issue being specific to Diablo 3 and will get you looking at your own network and that of your internet service provider.
- Use an online service like [pingtest.net](http://www.pingtest.net/) to determine the quality of your internet connection. Note that any results from this could also indicate that your local network is at fault (as it communicates with your computer) but anything shown on a service like pingtest.net will demonstrate that the issue is not with the game(s).
- If you connect to your router using WiFi, have a read through [this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21132/change-your-wi-fi-router-channel-to-optimize-your-wireless-signal/), which explains how to determine which WiFi channels have the most interference. If your current WiFi channel is in use by many of your neighbours, change your router to use another one that isn't as full. Interference will cause random latency and connectivity issues if you're using WiFi.
- If you have any other network devices on your network (other computers, tablets, smartphones, etc) ensure that they're not periodically checking for emails, updating Facebook apps, etc by removing them from your network completely for a period of time.
- If you're using an Ethernet cable to connect to your router, change it for another one and see if this resolves your problem.

If you're still having problems after trying these suggestions, I would personally contact your internet service provider and get them to have a look at the problems you're experiencing.

Comment: Excellent all-round diagnostic answer. I'd just like to add that I find running a ping in the background useful when attempting to identify what the problem is. For example, open up CMD/Terminal and use ``ping -t google.com``. Then, when you experience the issue, tab out and take a look. If the ping is still stable, that might point to a more game or game server specific problem.

Comment: @Kalina: mij ingame latency is about 1800....i did a ping test which gave me 32ms and download speed of 4.46 upload of 1.8. Before i rebuild my pc, latency was arround 18 to 200.....but now my pc runs on Windows 8. Any other suggestions to solve the problem???

Comment: A latency of 1.8 seconds is *very* high - especially since you're getting 32ms to pingtest.net. Do you consistently get latency this high when playing Diablo 3? Do you experience any of these issues when playing other games?

Comment: @kalina: I only play D3 and SC2 online and both have the problem......now i had even 4000msec in D3..... i start to think that it's something of battle.net/blizzard znd WINDOWS 8.....

Comment: I use Windows 8 and have no problems in any game. I would suggest contacting your internet service provider and see if they've got anything to say about it